# Sitecore Extranet login and PDF converter or Webclient

Tags: asp.net-membership, webclient, sitecore, winnovative

I'm having a problem using Winnovatives PDFConverter on pages that are protected by Extranet security (which is based on ASP.Net Membership).

I've tried several different approaches, but the following I can get to work on my local machine, but not anywhere else.

Code for login page, this code should bypass the login process for:

```
 // check that the current "user" isn't logged in and is the Winnovative UserAgent
 if (!Sitecore.Context.IsLoggedIn && Request.UserAgent.Contains(".NET CLR"))
        {
            //Login with a dummy user I've created
            Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.Login("extranet\\pdf", "pdf", true);
            //redirect to former page
        }
```

The page that generates the PDF uses this code:
private void PDFPrint(string url)
        {

```
        PdfConverter pdfConverter = new PdfConverter();           

        pdfConverter.LicenseKey = "our license";            

        url = Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Host + url;
        byte[] downloadBytes = pdfConverter.GetPdfFromUrlBytes(url);

        HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
        response.Clear();
        response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "binary/octet-stream");
        response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Sitecore.Context.Item.Name + ".pdf" + "; size=" + downloadBytes.Length.ToString());
        response.Flush();
        response.BinaryWrite(downloadBytes);
        response.Flush();
        response.End();
    }
```

The Exception I'm getting is this:

"Could not get the metafile from url. Could not get image from url.The URL is not accessible.."

I've also tried this trick from the Winnovative FAQ to no avail:
http://www.winnovative-software.com/FAQ.aspx#authenticationQ

I've also tried to use WebClient or HttpWebRequest to retrieve the content.

But nothing I do seems to work other than locally.

Basically I want to create a way of either getting Winnovatives converter to use the current logged in user, my custom "pdf" user og some other way of getting the html from the response.

I hope this question isn't too vague, but I find it kinda hard to ask. But basically I want to get some html content from a page on a Sitecore solution I control, which is protected by Sitecore normal Extranet security. This html content should be in string or byte[] format.

Help me Stackoverflowers, you're my only hope! :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I contacted Sitecore to ask if they had a solution.

Their solution was to create a Processor that would set an active user based on some criteria.

This is the code I made for my site (it's probably not the best solution as UserAgent can be spoofed):

```
public class MyResolver : HttpRequestProcessor
    {
        // Methods
        public override void Process(HttpRequestArgs args)
        {

            var userAgent = args.Context.Request.UserAgent ?? "";
            SiteContext site = Sitecore.Context.Site;
            if (site.Name == "site_name_in_webconfig" && userAgent.Contains("this_should_only_be_in_thepdfcreators_userAgent"))
            {
                Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User pdfuser = Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User.FromName("extranet\\theUser", true);
                AuthenticationManager.SetActiveUser(pdfuser);
            }

        }
    }
```

and then add the following to the web.config, before the UserResolver:

```
<processor type="Namespace.MyResolver, Assembly" />
```

I hope this will help some others out there.

Comment: Great idea to contact Sitecore, they always have the solutions ;-)

Comment: Yeah, I just thought this was more of a PDFConverter issue or an issue with Membership. But yeah, they do sometimes have some good answers, though I do feel they tend to say "send us the whole solution and databases", which usually results in me giving up as sending several GBs of production databases is too much of a hassle. :)

Answer (score 1):

I've found a similar issue on the ASP.NET forums and the answer to that was to use a newer version of the PDF tool: [SessionState Problems ?](http://forums.asp.net/t/1303207.aspx/1?SessionState%20Problems%20)

Comment: Hm... well the version we are using is 3.7 and there is a 7.0 version out now... unfortunately our license doesn't work with the newer version.